# regarding sigaction function

Tags: c, unix

i went through the sigaction function in stevens but was unable to understand .please anyone explain it in brief  the usage and application .thanks.

Comment: What didn't you understand? Although lacking portability, the old POSIX signal(2) is certainly simpler and you might want to try writing a test program with that and move up to the more complex sigaction(2).

Answer (score 1):

I described briefly what a signal is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215953/what-is-sig44-in-gdb/4216258#4216258).

sigaction function is used in order to change the action of a process when a signal is received. With sigaction you register a handler function that is called when a signal arrives. Once the signal is received, the handler function is called and you are able to define how and what the program shall do next.

sigaction function example [here](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Sigaction-Function-Example.html).